# Is there any way of checking if file system is case-insensitive in the preprocessors?

Tags: c, macos, filesystems, case-insensitive

I want to make a check in the preprocessor if the file system is case-insensitive.
Till now I was assuming macOS always has case-insensitive paths, but recently I read that it depends on file system.
I just needed a way to make this check in `#if`, so I can set my array size accordingly.

Comment: No you couldn't check something like that in the pre-processor since you haven't executed any code at the given time. Unless you mean check through some header files?

Comment: How could that work? The resulting executable could be run on a different machine, or even on a different filesystem on the same machine.

Comment: Try to `#include <STDIO.H>` and if that fails the filesystem is case sensitive and now `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: What's the relationship between the the case sensitivity of the file system and the size of whatever array?? And why do you need to know that anyway at compile time?

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. Please explain a bit more.

Comment: a good way is to eliminate the problem always supposing it is case sensitive

Comment: In general people would use case-insensitive file sys of macOS but its possible to use a case sensitive one. So I had a thought apple may have provided some ways for this. Like gcc provides a way to determine a 64 bit system by `__LP64__ `.

Comment: @TomKarzes, that solves it. Thanks

Comment: And note that the machine may have two disks / filesystems (or more), with one case insensitive and one case sensitive. So then you'd have to ensure that the program only read from one FS.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Its a trie, so array size actually matters. Eliminating 26 indexes from an array actually saves a lot of space and insertion time. (The nodes getting inserted are enough to make a difference)

Comment: This looks like a bad idea.  The host OS can have multiple filesystems, some of which are case-sensitive and some not.  Heck, the EXT4 filesystem is case-sensitive but can now also include case-insensitive directory trees.

Comment: @Mihir so you need to detect that at runtime for the exact file system your file are stored on rather than at compile time. But anyway, you can have different file systems on the same machine....

Comment: @ChristianGibbons, if that’s the case, then I guess yes its unsafe to do that `include` trick. Probably best idea would be if somehow I could find a macOS specific.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, yes probably there is no way around. But yea thanks to everyone for the explanations regarding this, helped a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be a very bad idea unless you have very specific needs. One system can have multiple file systems, where some are case sensitive and some are not. That's not even unusual. This alone proves that the task is impossible to solve in the general case. It's theoretically possible to do this at compile time for a given path. But to make it even worse, these circumstances can change. Let's say that your program read and/or writes to `/path/to/data`, and then the user decides to replace the file system with something else. Now your program is broken.

The best solution for most problems related to this is probably to not assume anything about the case sensitiveness during compilation. Find out during execution instead.

But one thing worth mentioning is that modern case insensitive filesystems do preserve the original case of the filename. An example of a filesystem that is non case preserving is FAT used in the old MS-DOS, but that filesystem is very rare today. You will find it hard to find someone who is not a retro-fan using them.

Comment: Regarding rare FAT partitions, what about the EFI system partition that is widely in use today?